# Objective C: Why can't I update a label from another class (AppDelegate > MainViewController)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uilabel

I've been trying to **update a UILabel** via a method call from **AppDelegate.m** to **MainViewController.m** for a while now. I really don't see why this isn't working. The **method gets called allright** and *everything works* **except** the very last bit of **changing/updating the label text**.

### Workflow

In `applicationDidBecomeActive` in **AppDelegate** call the method `updateLabelMethod` in **MainViewController** which processes data and updates label.

### Code

**MainViewController.h**

```
UILabel *daysResultOutlet;
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *daysResultOutlet;
@end

@interface MainViewController ()
    - (void) updateLabelMethod;
@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
@synthesize daysResultOutlet;
- (void) updateLabelMethod {
    NSString *value = @"test";
    NSLog(@"Testing to print value: %@",value);
    [daysResultOutlet setText:value]; //insert in label
}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
@end

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MainViewController *mvsAsObj = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [mvsAsObj updateLabelMethod]; //running function, value correctly logged but lbl not updated
    mvsAsObj.daysResultOutlet.text = @"update!!"; // not working!

}
```

### Results & Attempts

The **label does not get updated** either via cross class the method call `updateLabelMethod` or via `mvsAsObj.daysResultOutlet.text = @"update!!";` , however, the method gets called and its priting the value: `LOG: Testing to print value: test`. Furthermore, if I call this methods from within MainViewController: `[self updateLabelMethod]` everything works just fine.

I've tried basically all solutions there are but the thing is, what I'm doing here is straight off several Stackoverflow questions so I don't know how to proceed. I'm using storyboards.

**Any further ideas**?

Comment: ***This is not related to Xcode by any means.***

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to **Ryan Poolos** for pointing out the possibility of having my controller listen to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` instead of calling the method from AppDelegate. This is how i ended up doing it:

In MainViewControll, **ViewDidLoad**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(becomeActive:)
    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
    object:nil];

- (void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"active");
}
```

**Cleaning** up the notification

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you expect

```
MainViewController *mvsAsObj = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

to return the same instance of the view controller that already exists? `alloc` creates a new instance. Modifying it **obviously** won't have any effect on the other instance.

Comment: What @H2CO3 is saying is since you're using IBOutlet we assume you're using storyboard or interface builder to create the label. So you need to get THAT viewController instance and adjust it's label.

Comment: @RyanPoolos and how do I do that, can you give me an example? Bare with me here, I'm new to obj C and iOS developing :/

Comment: @H2CO3 you're going to have to be more clear here, instead of telling me what NOT to do, how about telling me what I should actually change to make it all work.. Something like changing that line to `MainViewController *mvsAsObj;` Constructivism, you know..

Comment: First off why are you trying to change the text in your App Delegate? These types of things should generally be done elsewhere.

Comment: @RyanPoolos because this method has to be run on `applicationDidBecomeActive`, ie not only when the app's first launched but every single time it's opened. As far as I know, this is (best) done in AppDelegate.

Comment: Well when using Storyboards the the AppDelegate isn't a safe place to do these types of calls. It would be better if you used NSNotificationCenter and subscribed to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notifications inside your `MainViewController`.

Comment: @RyanPoolos Ok, once again may I ask you to provide an example / tutorial link of how to do this? I see the mistake both of you guys point out but it doesn't really solve my problem. I need something more concrete. Thanks

Comment: A quick google for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` will bring up tons of tutorials and documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

did you connect the UILabel in the code to the actual label in the Storyboard/Nib file?

just asking because i tend to forget that at times as well...

Comment: Yes I have, it's something else